# An alternative for Geoserver for Drupal 8

Tags: drupal-8, geoserver

Since Drupal 8 is not compatible with Geoserver, is there any alternative way to Geoserver which should be connected / compatible  with drupal 8? 
Any idea about this? Can someone please help me?
 I am new to Geoserver and Drupal 8.

Thanks a lot in advance,

Comment: Can you explain why geoserver is not compatible with drupal?

Comment: No, I mean Geoserver is not compatible with Drupal 8. WIth Drupal 7 it is working. But i need to work on Drupal 8.

Comment: OK what doesn't work, GeoServer just sends images to the page based on a URL request.

Comment: thank you ...I wanted to know , is there any module in D8 which can be used as an alternative to geoserver . We will be using leaflet in D8. I don't know much about this, as i am a newbie in Drupal world.

Comment: you can access geoserver from Leaflet - http://leafletjs.com/examples/wms/wms.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Will it support Raster data? As i don't have any idea about geoserver , I will try it and will let you know.